# Django : Difference between django-admin.py and django-admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

Okay here's the catch. When I create a django project with `django-admin.py startproject myproject` and starts server like `python3 manage.py runserver`, it all works fine.

However, when I create project with `django-admin startproject myproject` and starts server like `python3 manage.py runserver`, it gives me tonnes of system check errors like :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Passing a 3-tuple to include() is not supported. Pass a 2-tuple containing the list of patterns and app_name, and provide the namespace argument to include() instead.
```

or

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
?: (admin.E408) 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
?: (admin.E409) 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
?: (admin.E410) 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware' must be in MIDDLEWARE in order to use the admin application.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should be the same, but I think somehow it is not same in your machine. Check your [**`django-admin version`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#determining-the-version) by:

```
django-admin version
django-admin.py version
```

For future reference, you should not use `django-admin.py` as it will be removed as entry point from **Django 4.0**. Please see the [Django Deprecation Timeline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#deprecation-removed-in-4-0) for more information.

Comment: my ``` django-admin version ``` is 1.8.2 while ``` django-admin.py version``` is 3.0.5. So, django-admin.py is same as my django version, so that's why it works. So what is the way to reconfigure ``` django-admin``` ?

Comment: Try updating django by  `python -m pip install -U Django`

Comment: When I run this, both django-admin and django-admin.py are set to 1.11.29. and project created with django-admin runs server without any faults. Thanks.!

Comment: it is using python2. you should use `python3 -m pip install -U Django`.